# Is it possible to recurse on a type hierarchy with distinct generic parameters in F#?

Tags: generics, recursion, parameters, f#, warnings

Let's say I have the following F# code:

```fsharp
[<AbstractClass>]
type Base<'a>() =
    class end
and Test<'a, 'b>(b: Base<'b>, c: 'b -> 'a) =
    inherit Base<'a>()
    member this.B = b
    member this.C = c

let rec test (b : Base<'a>) : _ =
    match b with
    | :? Test<'a, 'b> as t -> let result = test t.B
                                test (t.C result)
    | _                    -> failwith "Not supported!"
```

Basically, I would like to recurse on a type (Base<'b> in this case) with a generic parameter that is different to what I am currently using in the current function call (Base<'a> in this case).
For example, in the code I am pattern matching on some Base<'a> b, which might be an instance of Test, meaning I am in a function
call with Base<'a> currently.

Pattern matching on Test, I would like to recurse on it's field b of Base<'b>, i.e. a instance of Base that might have a different generic parameter than 'a.
HOWEVER, when I do this, on the line with (test t.B) I get the following warning, which totally destroys what I am trying to do:

> Warning FS0064: This construct causes code to be less generic than
> indicated by the type annotations. The type variable 'a has been
> constrained to be type 'b.

My question: Is it possible to get around this constraint/warning somehow in F#? I don't understand why the recursive call on t.B (let result = test t.B) would cause 'a to be same type as 'b. I would need the two to be able to be different for what I am trying to do.

Thanks.

EDIT: Added the actual code giving this issue (at: return NaiveEval con.Eff):

```fsharp
   type Channel<'a>() =
        let queue = ConcurrentQueue<'a>()
    
        member internal this.Send value =
                queue.Enqueue value
    
        member internal this.Receive =
                let status, value = queue.TryDequeue()
                if status then value else this.Receive

    [<AbstractClass>]
    type Effect<'Result>() =
        class end
    and Input<'Result>(chan : Channel<'Result>, cont : 'Result -> Effect<'Result>) = 
        inherit Effect<'Result>()
        member internal this.Chan = chan
        member internal this.Cont = cont
    and Output<'Result>(value : 'Result, chan : Channel<'Result>, cont : unit -> Effect<'Result>) =
        inherit Effect<'Result>()
        member internal this.Value = value
        member internal this.Chan = chan
        member internal this.Cont = cont
    and Concurrent<'Result, 'Async>(eff: Effect<'Async>, cont: Async<'Async> -> Effect<'Result>) = 
        inherit Effect<'Result>()
        member internal this.Eff = eff
        member internal this.Cont = cont
    and Await<'Result, 'Async>(future: Async<'Async>, cont: 'Async -> Effect<'Result>) =
        inherit Effect<'Result>()
        member internal this.Future = future
        member internal this.Cont = cont
    and Return<'Result>(value : 'Result) =
        inherit Effect<'Result>()
        member internal this.Value = value

    let Send(value, chan, cont) = Output(value, chan, cont)
    let Receive(chan, cont) = Input(chan, cont)
    
    let rec NaiveEval (eff : Effect<'Result>) : 'Result =
        match eff with
        | :? Input<'Result> as input             -> let value = input.Chan.Receive
                                                    NaiveEval <| input.Cont value
        | :? Output<'Result> as output           -> output.Chan.Send output.Value
                                                    NaiveEval <| output.Cont ()
        | :? Concurrent<'Result, 'Async> as con  -> let work = async {
                                                        return NaiveEval con.Eff
                                                    }
                                                    let task = Async.AwaitTask <| Async.StartAsTask work
                                                    NaiveEval <| con.Cont task
        | :? Await<'Result, 'Async> as await     -> let res = Async.RunSynchronously await.Future
                                                    NaiveEval <| await.Cont res
        | :? Return<'Result> as ret              -> ret.Value
        | _                                      -> failwith "Unsupported effect!"
```

Comment: I think you're mixing generic functions (compile-time logic) and reflection (run-time logic) in a way that isn't supported. Here's a question to think about: What is the intended return type of your `test` function?

Comment: In the end, the test function should return 'a, so the signature should really be (b : Base<'a>) : 'a

Comment: OK. Suggestion: Make `test`’s type parameters explicit, both in its signature (eg. `let rec test<‘a, ‘b> … =`) and when you call it recursively. I think you’ll see the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so after a lot of experimentation, I've finally been able to solve the problem. Thanks to @TomasPetricek, I've managed to built a sort of visitor pattern that allows what I am trying to do.

```ml
type EffectVisitor =
    abstract member VisitInput<'Result> : Input<'Result> -> 'Result
    abstract member VisitOutput<'Result> : Output<'Result> -> 'Result
    abstract member VisitConcurrent<'Result, 'Async> : Concurrent<'Result, 'Async> -> 'Result
    abstract member VisitAwait<'Result, 'Async> : Await<'Result, 'Async> -> 'Result
    abstract member VisitReturn<'Result> : Return<'Result> -> 'Result
and [<AbstractClass>] Effect() =
    abstract member Visit : EffectVisitor -> 'Result
and [<AbstractClass>] Effect<'Result>() =
    abstract member Visit<'Result> : EffectVisitor -> 'Result
and Input<'Result>(chan : Channel<'Result>, cont : 'Result -> Effect<'Result>) =
    inherit Effect<'Result>()
    member internal this.Chan = chan
    member internal this.Cont = cont
    override this.Visit<'Result>(input) =
    input.VisitInput<'Result>(this)
and Output<'Result>(value : 'Result, chan : Channel<'Result>, cont : unit -> Effect<'Result>) =
    inherit Effect<'Result>()
    member internal this.Value = value
    member internal this.Chan = chan
    member internal this.Cont = cont
    override this.Visit<'Result>(input) =
    input.VisitOutput<'Result>(this)
and Concurrent<'Result, 'Async>(eff : Effect<'Async>, cont : Async<'Async> -> Effect<'Result>) =
    inherit Effect<'Result>()
    member internal this.Eff = eff
    member internal this.Cont = cont
    override this.Visit<'Result>(con) =
        con.VisitConcurrent<'Result, 'Async>(this)
and Await<'Result, 'Async>(task : Async<'Async>, cont : 'Async -> Effect<'Result>) =
    inherit Effect<'Result>()
    member internal this.Task = task
    member internal this.Cont = cont
    override this.Visit<'Result>(await) =
        await.VisitAwait<'Result, 'Async>(this)
and Return<'Result>(value : 'Result) =
    inherit Effect<'Result>()
    member internal this.Value = value
    override this.Visit<'Result>(input) =
        input.VisitReturn<'Result>(this)

let Send(value, chan, cont) = Output(value, chan, cont)
let Receive(chan, cont) = Input(chan, cont)

let rec NaiveEval<'Result> (eff : Effect<'Result>) : 'Result =
    eff.Visit({
        new EffectVisitor with
            member _.VisitInput<'Result>(input : Input<'Result>) : 'Result =
                let value = input.Chan.Receive
                NaiveEval <| input.Cont value
            member _.VisitOutput<'Result>(output : Output<'Result>) : 'Result =
                output.Chan.Send output.Value
                NaiveEval <| output.Cont ()
            member _.VisitConcurrent(con) =
                let work = async {
                    return NaiveEval con.Eff
                }
                let task = Async.AwaitTask <| Async.StartAsTask work
                NaiveEval <| con.Cont task
            member _.VisitAwait(await) =
                let result = Async.RunSynchronously await.Task
                NaiveEval <| await.Cont result
            member this.VisitReturn<'Result>(ret : Return<'Result>) : 'Result =
                ret.Value
    })
```

Comment: Glad to hear you got it to work! I guess one thing that would be worth thinking about is whether the added type safety you get (thanks to this being based on a generic type) is actually worth it. It may be much easier to write this if `Effect` was not generic (or perhaps if you had generic `Effect<'T>` storing a non-generic "raw" value, represented as a simple DU). I've definitely sometimes sacrificed type safety for simplicity and readability and I think that's usually a good deal.

Comment: Hi @TomasPetricek, I have recently been thinking whether a new EffectVisitor will be instantiated every time the NaiveEval is called? I'm just thinking ... new EffectVisitor with ... might be expensive if a lot of recursive calls are happening.

Comment: @lyyel - Yes, that's correct - new instance will be allocated for each recursive call. I think this should not be a big issue - but the only good advice about performance is that you'll have to measure it... There might be a way to do this using value types (structs) which would eliminate the allocation (but I have not tried this).

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of issues here:

- You cannot pattern match against a type that has free type parameters - so `:? Test<'a, 'b> as t` will not work - ideally, this would match any `Test` and set `'a` and `'b` to the right types, but that's not how pattern matching works (and the type parameters have to be known to the compiler).
- You are also trying to have a recursive function that calls itself with differnet type parameters, which also is not allowed in F#.

You can come up with various more or less elegant workarounds. The following is one option:

```
type IOperation = 
  abstract Invoke : Test<'a, 'b> -> unit

and [<AbstractClass>] Base() = 
  abstract Invoke : IOperation -> unit

and [<AbstractClass>] Base<'a>() = 
  inherit Base()

and Test<'a, 'b>(b: Base<'b>, c: 'b -> 'a) =
  inherit Base<'a>()
  member this.B = b
  member this.C = c
  override this.Invoke(op) =
    op.Invoke(this)

let rec test (b : Base) : _ =
    b.Invoke
      ({ new IOperation with 
          member x.Invoke<'b, 'c>(t:Test<'b, 'c>) = 
            test t.B
      })
```

It adds a non-generic `Base` (so that you can write recursive `test` function) which then has an invoke method that takes `IOperation`. This then has a generic `Invoke` method that gets invoked with `Test<'b, 'c>` - with the right type parameters - by the implementation in `Test`.

I think this might let you do what you need - but it is hard to say without knowing what specifically are you trying to do!

Comment: Visitor pattern FTW 

Comment: @RomainDeneau Oh no, what have I done??

Comment: Hi Tomas. I'll try to implement this and report back. Thanks!

Comment: I tried fiddling around with your idea a little bit, but I am unable to figure how to get the functionality that I need. I need the whole test method (NaiveEval in my code above) to return a value of type 'Result instead of unit. I've added my actual code to my question.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to add an answer that sacrifices some type-safety for simpler code.

To illustrate, consider this type:

```ml
type Expr<'t> =
  | Constant of 't
  | Transform of Expr<obj> * (obj -> 't)
```

This is not type-safe, but we can provide a type-safe API like so:

```ml
module Expr = 

  let constant (t : 't) = Constant t

  let private erase (x : Expr<'t>) : Expr<obj> =
    match x with
    | Constant t -> Constant (box t)
    | Transform (e, f) -> Transform (e, f >> box)

  let map (f : 't -> 'u) (x : Expr<'t>) : Expr<'u> = 
    Transform (erase x, fun o -> f (unbox o))
```

Now, this will not pass the type-checker:

```ml
let rec compute (x : Expr<'t>) : 't = 
  match x with
  | Constant t -> t
  | Transform (x, f) -> compute x |> f
```

However, we can use a `static` `member`!

```ml
type ComputeHelper = 
  static member Compute<'t>(x : Expr<'t>) : 't = 
    match x with
    | Constant t -> t
    | Transform (x, f) ->
      let o = Compute(x)
      f x
```

And we can provide a nice functional API:

```ml
let compute (x : Expr<'t>) : 't = 
  ComputeHelper.Compute(x)
```